# Mouse forward/back shortcuts in winforms webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anyone know how I could make a mouse's back and forward shortcut buttons work within a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control?

/T

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the navigation commands:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.navigationcommands.aspx

Comment: Isn't commands WPF only? I must not use WPF in this particular case because of legacy code etc.

Comment: Sorry bout that, maybe this provides more answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54758/getting-the-back-fwd-history-of-the-windows-forms-webbrowser-control